# Query based on a composition of columns in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'd like to figure out how to query based on a composition of columns, eg the fullname of a user, without any custom SQL.  Is this possible?

Imagine something like
    User.objects.filter(firstname__concat__lastname__startswith="Barack Ob")

I know that in this particular example, it'd be easy enough to split "Barack Ob" by whitspace and modify the query, but is it possible to do a query on a composition of columns like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution to your question can be worked out if your database supports full text search. I use Postgresql ([see documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch.html)) and was able to make the following query work:

```
print User.objects.all().extra(where = 
     ["to_tsvector(coalesce(first_name) || coalesce(last_name)) 
      @@ to_tsquery('BarackObama')"])
```

You will note that I used the full name in the query. My knowledge of text search is limited and I don't know if there is a way to do the equivalent of `__startswith` (implemented using `LIKE`).

I suspect that this would be an overkill for your needs. You might be better off adding a custom field or custom method or a combination of the two to implement this.

Comment: A custom field for each combination of columns I want would be very bad for memory.  A custom method would mean that the filtering is done on the python side, and not by the RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

With the current Django ORM, no, it doesn't exist.  You do have access to the Q object query handler.

```
User.objects.filter(Q(firstname__startswith=name.split(" ", 1)[0]), Q(lastname__startswith=name.split(" ", 1)[1]))
```